# JS & CSS Script Optimizer return Error loading script

Tags: wordpress

I am using latest WordPress version with too many plugins, therefore site is too slow. For speedup my site I am using [JS & CSS Script Optimizer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/js-css-script-optimizer/).

After installing JS & CSS Script Optimizer plugin this plugin not loading any file, it return this error:

> /* jquery-ui-position:
>   (https://domain-name.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/position.min.js) */
>    /*Error loading script content: https://domain-name.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/position.min.js

Answer (score 0):

You need to install wp total cache plugin for this and enable option for css minify and js minify from admin

Hope it will works

Comment: I also try wp total cache, butt it seams same error.